# Solve the matrix equation $X = AX^T + B$ for $X$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Consider the matrix equation

> \begin{equation}
> X=AX^T+B,
> \end{equation}

where $X$ is an unknown square matrix. Is it possible to solve it analytically? Moreover, can a general solution be written down in terms of the matrices $A$ and $B$?

Comment: What is known about the dimensions of $X$?

Comment: It is a square matrix

Comment: You could try to use the `vec` operator, if you want a closed form.

Answer (score 4):

Assume $X$ is an $n \times n$ matrix.

If we rewrite the equation as:

$$ X - AX^T = B $$

then we have a system of $n^2$ linear equations in $n^2$ unknowns (the entries of $X$), so in general the existence of solutions $X$ can be computed by standard methods.

Comment: But can a general solution be written down in terms of the matrices $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Probably you are thinking of a solution $X$ that is a rational matrix expression formed from $A,B$.  That is not possible.  I will add something to my Answer to show why not.

Comment: Where are the $n^2$ equations coming from? I see $n$ equations in $n^2$ variables. Specifically, there exists some $F\in\mathbb{C}^{N \times N^2}$ such that $F\cdot \operatorname{vec}(X) = X - AX^{\mathrm{T}} = B$. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85: To say that $X - AX^T = B$ is to say the $n^2$ entries on the left-hand side equal the respective entries on the right-hand side.  The LHS entries are linear combinations of the unknown entries of $X$ (with coefficients involving known entries of $A$), and the RHS entries are known constants.  So this is a very typical linear system with as many equations as unknowns.  That said, the system may be inconsistent, have many solutions, or have a unique solution.  Regardless, solving that linear system is equivalent to solving the original matrix eqn.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85: As to where you went wrong, your formulation should be $F \cdot \text{vec}(X) = \text{vec}(X - AX^T) = \text{vec}(B)$ to make the square nature of the linear system evident.

Comment: @hardmath Thanks. I was mistakenly was reading $A$ and $B$ to be $n$-element vectors, but they are both $n \times n$.

Comment: @anonsub I worked this [out](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/605512), if you are interested...

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\fvo}{1}
\newcommand{\cdf}{\cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot}
\newcommand{\cdt}{\cdot & \cdot & \cdot}
\newcommand{\cdo}{\cdot}
\newcommand{\cdw}{\cdot}
 $

$\newcommand{\vec}{\text{vec}}$
$\newcommand{\lb}{\left(}$
$\newcommand{\rb}{\right)}$
$\newcommand{\unity}{\bf\text{1}}$ Use the superoperator formalism to rewrite
$X=AX^T+B$ as

$$
\vec(X)=\lb\unity\otimes A \rb\vec (X^T) +\vec(B)\\
\vec(X)-\lb\unity\otimes A \rb\vec (X^T)=\vec(B)\\
\lb \lb\unity\otimes \unity\rb -\lb\unity\otimes A \rb \hat T\rb \vec (X)=\vec(B),\\
$$
where $\hat T $ describes the Transposition Superoperator. For $4\times 4$ matrices this looks like

\begin{equation}
\widehat T :=
\left(\,
\begin{smallmatrix}
\fvo & \cdt & \cdf & \cdf & \cdf \\
\cdf & \fvo & \cdt & \cdf & \cdf \\
\cdf & \cdf & \fvo & \cdt & \cdf \\
\cdf & \cdf & \cdf & \fvo & \cdt \\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\cdo & \fvo & \cdw & \cdf & \cdf & \cdf \\
\cdf & \cdo & \fvo & \cdw & \cdf & \cdf \\
\cdf & \cdf & \cdo & \fvo & \cdw & \cdf \\
\cdf & \cdf & \cdf & \cdo & \fvo & \cdw \\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\cdw & \fvo & \cdo & \cdf & \cdf & \cdf \\
\cdf & \cdw & \fvo & \cdo & \cdf & \cdf \\
\cdf & \cdf & \cdw & \fvo & \cdo & \cdf \\
\cdf & \cdf & \cdf & \cdw & \fvo & \cdo \\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\cdt & \fvo & \cdf & \cdf & \cdf \\
\cdf & \cdt & \fvo & \cdf & \cdf \\
\cdf & \cdf & \cdt & \fvo & \cdf \\
\cdf & \cdf & \cdf & \cdt & \fvo \\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\\
\end{smallmatrix}\,
\right)
\end{equation}
(see for example [here](http://info.phys.unm.edu/%7Ecaves/courses/qinfo-f12/lectures/lectures14-17.pdf) eq. $(43)$).

If $\lb \lb\unity\otimes \unity\rb -\lb\unity\otimes A \rb \hat T\rb $ is invertible, you'll get
$$
\vec (X)=\lb \lb\unity\otimes \unity\rb -\lb\unity\otimes A \rb \hat T\rb ^{-1}\vec(B)
$$

Undo $\vec$ and you're done...

Comment: Think you're missing a transpose on $X$ on the second line.

Comment: @Roger thx. edited...